# Can email address be removed from iPad without risk deleting messages in iMessage?

Tags: icloud, ipados, messages

**One customer of mine inherited an iPad** from one of his grandparents.

For some time, he is using iMessage with its own phone number to converse with friends.
We are not sure if the iPad is still attached to his grandparent's Apple account, and if possibly if iMessage is in some way also linked to that account.

Mail (the email client) is linked to the grandparent's email address.
We want to detach this email account as the new owner doesn't want to access the messages of his grandparent, nor to download incoming emails from this address.

**Can we safely remove the email account in Mail, without risk of loosing the conversations in iMessage?**

Comment: Do you have the device in your possession? Do you have a screen shot showing how / where you’re removing the address? Also, a backup with control of the affected AppleID means you can mess up and still restore things.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the device is currently by the client. I planned removing the email account on a future visit, after making sure that there is no risk for iMessage conversations. I am not sure if the client has control of the affected AppleID ; he likely just got the tablet that was possibly configured long time ago.